# GLIDE Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 96000012 byte allocation with 15189568 free bytes and 74MB until OOM en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-glide

Estoy creando un visor de imágenes gigantes, al intentar descargar una imagen de 15MB [aquí par verla](http://youimg1.c-ctrip.com/target/tg/773/732/734/7ca19416b8cd423f8f6ef2d08366b7dc.jpg)

Como visor de la imagen uso [Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) que está optimizado para mostrar imágenes Grandes.

```
final SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
...
Glide.with(view.getContext())
        .load(srcImage).asBitmap()
        .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .error(R.drawable.error_image_load)
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(resource));
            }
        });
```

Me devuelve un

> GLIDE Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 96000012 byte allocation with 15189568 free bytes and 74MB until OOM

Lo curioso es que si lo cargo a un `imageView` normal no me salta el error, supongo como qeu el `imageView` no se puede agrandar, Glide debe eliminar de la memoria la gigante y solo una copia al tamaño del `imageView`

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
        .load(srcImage)
        .thumbnail(0.1f)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .error(R.drawable.error_image_load)
        .crossFade(1000)
        .into(imageView);
```

¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionar ese `OutOfMemory`?

Answer (score 1):

**Solventado**

Buscando exhaustivamente por SO he encontrado la solución `AndroidManifest.xml` se debe deshabilitar la aceleración por hardware y permitir el Heap sea más grande.

```
<application
    ...
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: No obstante y por curiosidad, ¿la imagen la cargabas en un Fragment? Por lo que sé, según como pases el contexto al cargar la imagen, ésta sigue el ciclo de vida de la actividad, por ejemplo al usar `with(getActivity())`  glide sigue el ciclo de vida de la actividad y no del fragment, por lo que si solo cierras el Fragment, aun estará ocupando memoria. Pero si te ocurría al cargar únicamente una imagen , entonces  tu solución es correcta.

Comment: Buenas, si que la tengo dentro de un fragment, pues probaré con getActivity() y quitando lo que he encontrado.

Comment: Probaria con `with((Fragment)this)` ó `with(this)` para que siga el ciclo de vida del fragment